# Custom boolean deserializer not working in Gson

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson

I have to deserialize `0` to `false` and `1` to `true`.

I've created this class:

```
class IntBooleanDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Boolean?> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): Boolean? {
        json?.let {
            return json.asInt == 1
        }

        return null
    }
}
```

And registered it:

```
private val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean::class.java, IntBooleanDeserializer())
            .create()
```

And created test class for this:

```
data class BooleanClass(val value: Boolean?)
```

And then:

```
gson.fromJson("{\"value\": 0}", BooleanClass::class.java)
```

This code throws exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a boolean but was NUMBER at line 1 column 12 path $.value
```

Seems that Gson does not use my deserializer for `Boolean?`, but successfully uses other custom deserializers for other types (for example, for enums).

Why?

Comment: Is `Boolean::class.java` the same as `Boolean?::class.java` (that is non-null vs. nullable) or is the latter undefined in Kotlin? I must admit my knowledge of Kotlin is patchy, but you register a deserialiser for `Boolean` and your data structure type is `Boolean?`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're registering the deserializer for `Boolean::class.java` which is `boolean` while the type you require actually is `Boolean?` translating to `java.lang.Boolean`.

To get `java.lang.Boolean` you have to use `Boolean::class.javaObjectType` for the registration.

You'd also find the same behavior for all primitive *Java* types.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [@tynn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3385212/tynn)'s answer and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091868/gson-converting-integer-value-to-boolean-value-dynamically-for-specific-fields). I design two `TypeAdater`s to cover `Boolean` and `Boolean?` type in Kotlin.

```kotlin
private val TRUE_STRINGS: Array<String> = arrayOf("true", "1")

class BooleanObjectTypeAdapter : JsonDeserializer<Boolean?>, JsonSerializer<Boolean?> {

    override fun serialize(src: Boolean?, typeOfSrc: Type?, context: JsonSerializationContext?): JsonElement {
        return if (src == null) {
            JsonNull.INSTANCE
       } else {
           JsonPrimitive(src)
       }
    }

    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): Boolean? {
        if (json == null || json.isJsonNull) {
            return null
        }

        return when {
            json !is JsonPrimitive -> false
            json.isBoolean -> json.asBoolean
            json.isNumber -> json.asNumber.toInt() == 1
            json.isString -> TRUE_STRINGS.contains(json.asString.lowercase())
            else -> false
        }
    }
}

class BooleanPrimitiveTypeAdapter : JsonDeserializer<Boolean>, JsonSerializer<Boolean> {

    override fun serialize(src: Boolean?, typeOfSrc: Type?, context: JsonSerializationContext?): JsonElement {
        return if (src == null) {
            JsonPrimitive(false)
        } else {
            JsonPrimitive(src)
        }
    }

    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): Boolean {
        if (json == null || json.isJsonNull) {
            return false
        }

        return when {
            json !is JsonPrimitive -> false
            json.isBoolean -> json.asBoolean
            json.isNumber -> json.asNumber.toInt() == 1
            json.isString -> TRUE_STRINGS.contains(json.asString.lowercase())
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

You can register these adapters by

```kotlin
GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean::class.javaObjectType, BooleanObjectTypeAdapter())
    .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType, BooleanPrimitiveTypeAdapter())
    .create()
```

I also create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/samuel22gj/dbbe1df999baed6de8fdf074ffcb11aa) to keep these and write tests.